# mktime returns -1 but valid data

Tags: c++, mktime

I try to find a way for a default date (if date is not valid).
Common way works fine:

```
set(2022,6,17,12,12,0,0,0)

void KTime::Set(int nYear, int nMonth, int nDay, int nHour, int nMin, int nSec, int nDST, bool isUTC)
{
    assert(nYear >= 1900);
    assert(nMonth >= 1 && nMonth <= 12);
    assert(nDay >= 1 && nDay <= 31);
    assert(nHour >= 0 && nHour <= 23);
    assert(nMin >= 0 && nMin <= 59);
    assert(nSec >= 0 && nSec <= 59);

    struct tm atm;
    atm.tm_sec = nSec;
    atm.tm_min = nMin;
    atm.tm_hour = nHour;
    atm.tm_mday = nDay;
    atm.tm_mon = nMonth - 1;        // tm_mon is 0 based
    atm.tm_year = nYear - 1900;     // tm_year is 1900 based
    atm.tm_isdst = nDST;
    m_time = isUTC ? utc_mktime(&atm) : mktime(&atm);

    assert(m_time != -1);       // indicates an illegal input time
}
```

But if I set to the same function:

```
set(1900,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
```

I will get a mktime = -1
Any idea where is my logic bomb?

Comment: `KTime::Set` is definitely not C, and then you can `set` which isn't a valid function here. But in C++ why don't just use `std::chrono`?

Comment: KTIme is an own class for time handling. This function is just to validate the given date, not to fill any values or parameter.

Comment: yes, `std::chrono` is the Swiss-knife for date/time handling and it contains everything, no need to resort to ancient C tools. The code would be much shorter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mktime` (and the rest of the POSIX date functions) only work for dates >= 1970-01-01 00:00:00, [the UNIX epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Encoding_time_as_a_number).

`mktime`, [quoth the manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/mktime),

> returns -1 if time cannot be represented as a time_t object

and 1900 definitely can't be represented as a time_t, since it's 70 years early.

Comment: [*The GNU C Library additionally guarantees that `time_t` is a signed type, and that all of its functions operate correctly on negative `time_t` values, which are interpreted as times before the epoch.*](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Time-Types.html) so if you use the GNU libc then it should work

Comment: Ok, this 1971 (mktime only accepts 1971) magic was not known. On Windows it is common 1900. Thank you for that hint.